# Replace values with different condition in multiple columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe something like this but much larger:

```
source  next1     next2     next3
  b1     {-}       b2      -,b2,b3
  b2,b3      -   {b2,b3}  {b2,b3,b4}
```

Now I need to replace a lot of characters here. Every next column should contain values of previous. If the value is -, or {-} that means previous, and if it's not any of that, again, there need to be previous. 
Desired output:

```
source  next1  next2     next3
 b1      b1      b2     b1,b2,b3
 b2,b3   b2,b3   b2,bb3 b2,b3,b4
```

I have tried something like this:

```
for val in df['source'].values:
    if values=b1:
        df['next1'].replace('{-},', 'b1,',regex=True, inplace=True)
        df['next1'].replace('-,', 'b1,',regex=True, inplace=True)
```

etc
But I have so much rows, and condiditons, so this works to long and not where precise, there are errors. Put one value (from replacing) to all rows.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a fast solution to your question, as string operations will always be slow-ish. Still, there is a better/faster one.

A straight-forward solution would be

```
for i in range(1, df.shape(1)):  # here only order matters
    df.iloc[:, i].str.replace('{-}', '-', inplace=True)
    mask = df.iloc[:, i].str.contains('-')
    df.iloc[mask, i].str.replace('{-}', df.iloc[mask, i-1], inplace=True)
```

with that, it is likely to be WAY faster to have all the columns as sets ({}) and operate on them as such.

Comment: Thank you for this part. Is there any way to add (+) string values from one column to another, but keep just unique. For example  after addition : b1, b2, b1, b3. How to keep just b1, b2, b3 as a value?

Comment: I think it is
1) possible with some code
2) really a horrible idea. Why are you trying to recreate `sets` in form of strings, instead of working on sets and then (if necessary) transforming them to string at the very end?

I think you should go back to where you get your data from, and either find a way to get sets instead or parse your strings into sets. After that, your problem would boil down to adding two sets (and removing `-`) in the loop above. 

a sloppy parsing approach would be something like `set(el.replace("{-}", '-').replace('{', '').replace('}', '').split(','))`